# what the best way to erase parameters

Tags: linux, bash, parameters

in my bash script I erase the parameters because function in my script are using the same parameters ,

As the following

```
Func1 ()

{

 Param1=””
 Param2=””
 Param3=””

  }

 Func2 ()

 {

   Param1=””
   Param2=””
   Param3=””


     }
```

But the way to erase the parameter by equal it to “”
Isn’t so elegant

Please advice what the other ways to erase parameters in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare them as `local` if you want to limit their visibility:

```
Func1()
{
local Param1
local Param2
....
}
```

and so on so that you don't have to "reset" them in other places.

Comment: but if I want to create function that erase all the parameters then what is the case for that?  ( I want to call this function from other function )

Comment: Not sure what by "erase" all parameters. If you are not interested in what params are passed, then you can ignore them or not pass them at all. Why do you want to deliberately erase them?

Comment: I think unset command is more fit for me as unset Param1 , what you think?

Comment: I need to erase the parameters because in my bash I call other function that use the saem parameters and to avoid previos values that are not relevant

Comment: what you think about my answer?

Comment: You don't seem to understand why using `local` is better, but it is. You should avoid using global variables in the first place.

Comment: @maihabunash `unset` is a way but `local` is much better. You make variables local in the first place rather than going after global variables tounset them. Prevention is better than cure :)

Answer (score 0):

it can be use by unset command

```
  Func1()

   {
    unset Param1
    unset Param2
    ....
   }

 # call to func in order to erase the parameters

Func1
```

so evry time I want to erase then I call the Func1